# UFW not Allowing Port 80 and 443 and 81

Tags: nginx, firewall, ufw

Good Day,
I have been using Nginx Proxy Manager and UFW firewall for quiet a while now, I recently had a domain change so my reverse proxy stopped working and I had to update my DNS records with my new domain accordingly..
After the changes when i checked with an online port checker other ports like: 25565 (Minecraft) say Open but ports like 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) and 81 (Nginx Proxy Manager Admin Portal) say Close..
I simply ran a check on google for my problem and tried everything as far as to resetting UFW, yet it doesn't open those ports.. It able to open others.. Now these ports were working before with UFW but now they aren't I tried firewall-cmd and that worked.. I'm extremely fond of UFW and don't really want to use firewall-cmd any suggestions on how I fix this.. Help will be really appreiciated..